# How to include generated source files when Play compiles?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

How can I include generated source files when my Play routes and views are compiled?

My Play 2.3 application uses a plugin that generates source files under a `sourceManaged` subdir (target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/subdir). These source files include controllers and models that are referenced in my routes files and views. But when I compile my application, I get errors like this:

```
[error] myapp/conf/routes:14: object Contacts is not a member of package controllers
[error] GET     /contacts                   controllers.Contacts.blank()
```

and this:

```
[error] myapp/app/views/contact/form.scala.html:1: not found: type Contact
[error] @(contactForm: Form[Contact])
[error] ^
```

Because `controllers/Contacts.java` and `models/Contact.java` reside under sourceManaged.

I've tried manually adding the appropriate managed sources subdir to `sourceDirectory in Compile` and `javaSource in Compile` in my build.sbt but it did not improve things.

I have considered making the managed source subdir a subproject and then using `aggreate()`, but it does not have the necessary build.sbt or project files -- it only has Java sources. And it seemed that making a managed source directory into a subproject from might be inappropriate. Should I reconsider this?

Comment: Is this an open-source project we can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the plugin has a way to be added to `sourceGenerators in Compile` by your Play project.  You can find how to do this [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Classpaths.html#unmanaged-v-managed) in the sbt documentation.  I also have [an example](https://github.com/joescii/snmp4s/blob/master/sbt/Snmp4sSbtPlugin.scala#L13-L16) in a plugin I wrote, but note that it uses 0.12.x syntax.

Once you've done that, be sure one of your Play project build files adds the settings.  This will be as simple as adding the name you used for the settings in the plugin to the build file, like [this example](https://github.com/joescii/snmp4s/blob/master/example/build.sbt#L13) of my plugin shows.